# Spark reading parquet compressed data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have nested JSON converted to Parquet (snappy) without any flattening. The structure, for example, has the following:

{"a":{"b":{"c":"abcd","d":[1,2,3]},"e":["asdf","pqrs"]}}

```
df = spark.read.parquet('<File on AWS S3>')

df.createOrReplaceTempView("test")
query = """select a.b.c from test"""
df = spark.sql(query)
df.show()
```

When the query is executed, does Spark read only the lowest-level attribute column referenced in query or does it read the top-level attribute that has this referenced attribute in its hierarchy?

Comment: Not sure I get the question, even if 2 upvotes. What am I missing?